# Указатель на функцию класса

Tags: callback, c++

Доброго всем времени суток! Хочу реализовать своеобразный Callback. Хочу, чтобы из метода одного класса вызывался метод другого класса. Функции вне классов, описанные и реализованные вне классов и функции main() вызвать получилось, а вот с методами классов не получается.
Пишу вот такое объявление функции в классе `Foo` для вызова функции класса `Child`:
`void foo(void(Child::*pFunc)(int));`
Но эта запись неверна. Может кто-то написать правильное определение или дать ссылку? Заранее благодарю!

Comment: Да вроде бы все правильно. Попробую догадаться, где возникает ошибка: при вызове функции через этот указатель.

Comment: @mikillskegg, нет, у меня именно ошибку Qt Creator выдавал во время объявления функции. Он подчёркивал красной линией этот метод. Там проблема как бы в синтаксисе была. Но в целом, Вы правы. Я пытался вызвать функцию без объекта.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Посмотри тут: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1738313/c-using-class-method-as-a-function-pointer-type
Там в посте от Michael Burr вроде бы как раз то что тебе надо написанно.

Вот еще: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1485983/calling-c-class-methods-via-a-function-pointer

Comment: Проблему решил. Нужно было сделать forward declaration нужного класса и в метод передать указатель или ссылку на объект класса Child.